# C# console + Unicode

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, utf-8, console

First of all, `Console.OutputEncoding` doesn't help. So i go on [unicode table site](http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/chess-symbols/), choose some symbols and try to output something. But only `??` is produced. Where am I wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
            string s = "\u2654\u2657";
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how about start by telling us what it is you're expecting to output
Try setting your output to this if it's ASCII `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode`

Comment: It seems to be difficult to find a mono-spaced font suitable for the console window which provides glyphs for the Unicode code-points from your code example. Neither Lucida Console, Consolas nor Courier New do... :(

Comment: I wonder if storing the values in a textfile and then streaming them with the necessary Encoding would also help

Comment: @DJKRAZE i expected the same result as winform textbox etc. I thinked that console app has full unicode support. This is what i was expected for.

Comment: Consoles are stuck with the Unix legacy and can only support 8-bit encodings (because of I/O redirection) and fixed-pitched fonts (because of terminal emulation).  The intersection is a small one, there is no fixed-pitched font on Windows that has the chess piece glyphs.  Not much point in pursuing this when it is so easy these days to implement real GUI apps.  And of course a *real* console app uses K and Q, only way to get the true retro-look :)

Comment: @HansPassant tnx, it looks like an answer

Answer (score 0):

The default font in the console window is not a Unicode font. You have to change it to a Unicode font like Lucida Console or Consolas so that it can display characters outside the regular 8-bit codepage.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.outputencoding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Under Remarks:

> Note that successfully displaying Unicode characters to the console
>   requires the following:
>
> - The console must use a TrueType font, such as Lucida Console or Consolas, to display characters.
> - A font used by the console must define the particular glyph or glyphs to be displayed. The console can take advantage of font linking
>     to display glyphs from linked fonts if the base font does not contain
>     a definition for that glyph.

Answer (score 0):

Tried you code in `http://www.compileonline.com/compile_csharp_online.php` worked find, as @Guffa said make sure your console encoding is capable to decode mentioned characters.